# Memory map in IDA Pro similar to OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, memory, ollydbg, ida

Does IDA Pro have a memory mapping functionality similar to that in OllyDbg? If so, I can't find it. I know there is that skinny bar at the top of the screen showing where you are in the address space and where memory is allocated, but I consider that kind of inadequate. This is what the memory map looks like in OllyDbg:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Program Segmentation

in View > Open Subview > Segments

but it doesn't have that detailed information as OllyDbg has.

Comment: view->open subview -> segments (shift+f7 ) will have a full memory map when debugging only and only after single stepping atleast one instruction (before clicking start process you may need to set debug options events stop on debugging start )