# Viewing permissions in Windbg

Tags: windbg, windows-kernel

I wanted to know how to view permissions(rwx) in Windbg of DLL like viewing it in Linux:

```
cat /proc/{id}/maps
08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windbg memory map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722345/windbg-memory-map)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I need for user-mode and kernel mode also. it says it is for user-mode, But I don`t see all the fields in my windbg appear like in his answer(where it says for RWX)

Comment: Don't look for RXW. We have PAGE_NOACCESS, PAGE_READONLY, PAGE_READWRITE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ etc.

Comment: !vadump will give a detailed map of process address space. and in kernel !vad or virtual address descriptor for the implicit process context if this is what you seek ill convert this comment to answer